# How to reorder Book module menu through Database?

Tags: routes, nodes, navigation

How to re-order Book menu faster, optionally through Database?

I have a big problem to reorder menu/ navigation for Book module....

It is supposed by drag-and-drop - I have 318 items in list , some 100 items to drag down for some 200 items; dragging seems refusing to work, as well as assigning weights....

(dragging was working on other menus, still taking a lot of time, because they are placed by default alphabetically not as submitted)

Is there any way to arrange those navigations faster or in database?

Comment: "dragging seems refusing to work, as well as assigning weights" - how so? If you click "show row weights", it fails for you? Or there is some error? Or what, exactly, happens?

Comment: long story.... Yesterday I submitted....218 items...and some part of them started to order and save by dragging....It was working, but slow and I was tired....Today I submitted like 100 the rest items....and started to drag... it doesn't work....items from yesterday are showing some row weights 218, 217, 216....etc... the new ones go with weight 0 at the back...still...I was trying to drag, but they didn't fixed positions...the same with Weight...There is weight, but if I change and save - I get all the old state..

Comment: I bet it's 'menu_links' table and Weight value in DB , and flush cache well....but I'm not over yet...

Comment: Try [Outline Designer](https://www.drupal.org/project/outline_designer)